# "look up" in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have made a contact manager, I have:

```
def look_up_contact():
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    choice = input("Please enter the last name of the contact you would like to view: ")
    print("-------------------------------------------------")
    person_list = Contacts[choice]
    try:
        for person in person_list:
            print("Contact: " + person.get_last_name() + ", " + person.get_first_name())
            print("Phone Number: " + person.get_phone_num())
            if type(person) == Friend:
                print("Email: " + person.get_email())
                print("Birthday: " + person.get_birth_date())
```

How could I modify this to also look in a text file?

I understand the basics, but this has been tricky

```
textcontacts = open( 'contacts.txt' )
```

I also have a would like some feedback about adding an error message if person could not be found in  'person' or txt:

I have attempted to do the try: method

```
except Exception as ex:
    print(' Sorry, The person you are looking for could not be found ')
```

I am using python 3.x

Comment: after `open`ing the file, try `for line in contacts:`. Try printing that out and see what happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
from collections import namedtuple


class ContactNotFoundError(Exception):
pass


def look_up_contact():
print('----------------------------------')
choice = input("Please enter the last name of the contact you would like to view: ")
print('----------------------------------')
Contact = namedtuple("Contact", "FirstName LastName PhoneNumber Email BirthDate")
with open('ListOfContacts.txt', 'r') as listOfNames:
    searchLines = listOfNames.readlines()
isFound = False
for line in searchLines:
    if choice in line:
        isFound = True
        Contact(*line.split(','))
if not isFound:
    raise ContactNotFoundError


if __name__ == '__main__':
look_up_contact()
```

HTH,
Phil

Answer (score 1):

You could use a dictionary. Perhaps a the code would be easier to read and the access to data faster (and it is more pythonic):

```
person_list = {}

person_list["friend1"] = {}

person_list["friend1"]["number"] = 1234567890
person_list["friend1"]["email"] = 'blabla@gmail.com'
person_list["friend1"]["friend"] = True
```

The you could simply look-up if a friend is in the list by doing:

```
if "friend1" in person_list:
    ...
else
    ...
```

Then to print in nicer way you could use PrettyPrint:

```
import pprint
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter()
pp.pprint(person_list)
```

And this is the result:

```
{'friend1': {'email': 'blabla@gmail.com',
             'friend': True,
             'number': 1234567890}}
```